# How to add a bottom sheet after tapping a google map marker in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want a bottom sheet to be displayed on tapping a google map marker in order to show details of the place.

Comment: What did you try? Add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    controller.onMarkerTapped(_onMarkerTapped);
}

_onMarkerTapped(Marker markerTapped) {
     showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child: Text('Write your text',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0
                    )
                  )
                )
              );
      });


}
```